# Passing JSONObject in RestFul Webservice

Tags: java, json, rest

I am using `RestFul Webservice` with `JBoss Server` to deploy the app to  receive the `JSONObject` to my `web service` ,to test that i have created the `web service` and written test cases for it .Now i got hung up in passing the `JSONobject` from test case to web services , when i pass the json object to `@post service` calls it responses that `Null Pointer Exception` , even i have tried with passing string to it it responds `null` values. 
I have used `Annotations` as follows  in `webservice`

```
@consumes({Mediatype.APPLICATION_JSON})

@Consumes("application/json")
```

Test case As:

```
    @Test
   public void testgetmsg() {
    String msg = "{\"patient\":[{\"id\":\"6\",\"title\":\"Test\"}]}";
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(msg));
            WebResource resource = client.resource( "https://localhost:8443/../../resources/create");
        ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                        entity(obj).post(ClientResponse.class,JSONObject.class);
                 }
    }
```

can any body guide me to proceed further ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the json object, you can just pass the string.

you should

```
 ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                   .post(ClientResponse.class, msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//CLIENT

public static void createStudent() {
    String input = "{\"id\":12,\"firstName\":\"Fade To Black\",\"lastName\":\"Joy\"}";
    ClientResponse response = service.path("class/post")
            .type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);
    System.out.println(response.getStatus()+ "OK");
}
```

Instead of using code client you can use add on firefox (POSTER) to passing value as json or formparam...

```
  // create new student SERVER
   //class

   @POST
   @Path("post")
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response createStudent(Student st) {
       // add new student 
       StudentDAO.instance.getModelStudent().put("8", st);
       // response status code
       return Response.status(200).entity(st).build();
    }
```